# Can I use "and" in this case.

Tags: lists

I am writing about a fantastical creature and was unsure of how to describe it grammatically. It is combination of two different animals and was wondering if I could use "and" repeatedly in this way:

"The creature had the body of a turtle and the head and legs of a lion."

Comment: If you put another **had** after the first and you can.

Comment: Or even if you don't.

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem with the sentence but you can use my word :

```
 The creature had the body of a turtle with the head and legs of a lion.
```

Comment: Please add an explanation why your sentence is better, which I agree it is.